# how to create Rest web services in java with OAuth 1.0

Tags: java, rest, oauth

I am new to RESTful web services. so please can anyone guide me how to create one with both client and server using OAuth 1.0.
if possible, please give me some example.

Comment: i am new to this, just seen a couple of tutorials but nothing is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn them in steps and then integrate. Here are couple of links to help you with that:

Learn how to write RESTful webservice using jersey, very simple tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/

Learn how to integrate OAuth with jersey :

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/OAuth

Final step : You assembling the knowledge and coming up with RESTful webservice using jersey with OAuth.

While coding it if you get stuck or see horrible exceptions, come back and post them here. You will surely get help when you show the right attitude. Good luck!